# Hapi/Joi alternatives when is - testing for regex

Tags: javascript, hapi.js, joi

I'm having the following joi schema:

```
const schema = Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().required(),
    resource: Joi.object({
        uri: Joi.string(),
    }),
    fov: Joi.alternatives().when('resource.uri', {
        is: Joi.string().regex(/\.jpg$/),
        then: Joi.any().forbidden(),
        otherwise: Joi.number().required()
    })
});
```

I was expecting that when I would send the following request body

```
{
    name: 'name', 
    resource: {
         uri: 'file.jpg'
    }, 
    fov: 10
}
```

I would get an error, because the regex of the when.is condition will match `'file.jpg'` and therefore `fov` will be validated as `Joi.any().forbidden()`. But the validation seems to be ignored. Do you have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

By posting the question I foung the answer:

My initial validation object looked like this:

```
resource: Joi.object({
    uri: Joi.alternatives().try(
        Joi.string(),
        Joi.array().max(config.objectTargets.maxImages).items(Joi.string())
    ),
    fov: Joi.alternatives().when('resource.uri', {
        is: Joi.string().regex(/\.wto$/),
        then: Joi.any().forbidden(),
        otherwise: Joi.number().required()
    }),
})
```

So it was looking for `resource.uri` inside the `resource` property. The solution is to have the when condition to be a reference to just `uri`, like here:

```
resource: Joi.object({
    uri: Joi.alternatives().try(
        Joi.string(),
        Joi.array().max(config.objectTargets.maxImages).items(Joi.string())
    ),
    fov: Joi.alternatives().when('uri', {
        is: Joi.string().regex(/\.wto$/),
        then: Joi.any().forbidden(),
        otherwise: Joi.number().required()
    }),
})
```

Sorry for not being more attentive before

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that it is perfectly working, but the error is not thrown, it is included in the return value :

```
const Joi = require('joi');

const schema = Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().required(),
    resource: Joi.object({
        uri: Joi.string(),
    }),
    fov: Joi.alternatives().when('resource.uri', {
        is: Joi.string().regex(/\.jpg$/),
        then: Joi.any().forbidden(),
        otherwise: Joi.number().required()
    })
});

const testVal = format => ({
    name: 'name',
    resource: {
         uri: format
    },
    fov: 10
});

const png = 'file.png';
const jpg = 'file.jpg';

const testPng = testVal(png);
const testJpg = testVal(jpg);

console.log(Joi.validate(testJpg, schema));
console.log("------------------------------");
console.log(Joi.validate(testPng, schema));
```

---

Gives this result :

```
{ error: 
   { ValidationError: child "fov" fails because ["fov" is not allowed]
    at Object.exports.process (/home/boehm-s/tmp/node_modules/joi/lib/errors.js:196:19)
    at internals.Object._validateWithOptions (/home/boehm-s/tmp/node_modules/joi/lib/types/any/index.js:675:31)
    at module.exports.internals.Any.root.validate (/home/boehm-s/tmp/node_modules/joi/lib/index.js:138:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/boehm-s/tmp/plop.js:29:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
     isJoi: true,
     name: 'ValidationError',
     details: [ [Object] ],
     _object: { name: 'name', resource: [Object], fov: 10 },
     annotate: [Function] },
  value: { name: 'name', resource: { uri: 'file.jpg' }, fov: 10 },
  then: [Function: then],
  catch: [Function: catch] }
------------------------------
{ error: null,
  value: { name: 'name', resource: { uri: 'file.png' }, fov: 10 },
  then: [Function: then],
  catch: [Function: catch] }
```

`fov` is not allowed because `ressource.uri` matches the regex that you provided.